# Web file hosting portal with ability to create custom links and folders

Tags: open-source, web-apps, file-management, php

There are a lot of PHP uploading scripts, but I don’t find one with certain features, preferably open-source but not required.

It should have the same philosophy like http://tlk.io/ where users (without registration) can create a chat room with custom name and access it directly using the room name, for example "tlk.io/myroom".

In this case, I want a web software (which I can host myself) where users can create folders with custom name and upload inside all files they want and then share a user-friendly link using the folder name.